# Nested fields in mongodb Documents with scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

When upgrading the mongodb connection from a scala application from Mongodb+Casbah to mongo-scala-driver 2.3.0 (scala 2.11.8) we are facing some problems when creating the Documents to insert in the DB. Basically I'm facing problems with nested fields of the type Map[String,Any] or Map[Int,Int].

If my field is of type Map["String", Int] there's no problem and the code would compile no problem:

```
val usersPerPage = Map("home" -> 23, "contact" -> 12) //Map[String,Int]
Document("page_id" -> pageId, "users_per_page" -> Document(usersPerPage))  
//Compiles 

val usersPerTime = Map(180 -> 23, 68 -> 34) //Map[Int,Int]
Document("page_id" -> pageId, "users_per_time" -> Document(usersPerTime)) 
//Doesn't compile

val usersConf = Map("age" -> 32, "country" -> "Spain") //Map[String,Any]
Document("user_id" -> userId, "user_conf" -> Document(usersConf)) 
//Doesn't compile
```

I've tried many workarounds but I'm not able to create a whole Document to insert with fields of the type Map[Int,Int] neither Map[String,Any], I thought by upgrading to a newer version of Mongo would make things easier.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind that the type `Map[Int,Int]` is not a valid Document map, as [Documents](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/bson/collection/immutable/Document.html) are
    `k,v -> String, BsonValue` format.

This will therefore compile:

```
val usersPerTime = Map("180" -> 23, "68" -> 34) //Map[String,Int]
Document("page_id" -> pageId, "users_per_time" -> Document(usersPerTime))
```

For both cases, do it directly with a Document class instead of Map:

```
val usersConf = Document("age" -> 32, "country" -> "Spain") 
Document("user_id" -> userId, "user_conf" -> usersConf)
```

This works well with `"org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.1.0"`